# Swift: opening the connection to server using CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost function failed how do I fix it?

Tags: swift

I want so send a message to the localhost on port number 80 but I was able to open a connection What did i do wrong and how can I fix it?

Here is the code to connect to the localhost server

```
class client:NSObject {
      var inputstream = InputStream!
      var outputstream = OutputStream!

      func setupNetworkCom() {
          var readstream = Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
          var writestream = Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

          CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, "localhost" as CFString, 80, &readstream, &writestream)

          inputstream = readstream!.takeRetainedValue()
          outputstream = writestream!.takeReatainedValue()

          inputstream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
          outputstream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)

          inputstream.open()
          outputstream.open()
      }
}
```

It gives me this error

```
2020-02-25 17:32:49.388120+0530 Test[3800:171412] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
2020-02-25 17:32:50.389186+0530 Test[3800:171412] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
2020-02-25 17:32:51.389589+0530 Test[3800:171412] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
2020-02-25 17:32:52.392031+0530 Test[3800:171412] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:5 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
2020-02-25 17:32:52.392319+0530 Test[3800:171412] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
2020-02-25 17:32:52.392724+0530 Test[3800:171411] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 1 Connection has no connected handler
2020-02-25 17:32:52.392754+0530 Test[3800:171411] TCP Conn 0x600000163a80 Failed : error 0:-65563 [-65563]
```

I downloaded the server from this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/3437391-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios#toc-anchor-010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question and your [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426901/swift-i-cant-get-the-client-script-to-connect-to-the-localhost-server-the-tcp) have the same answer you're missing the entitlement in the capabilities tab.

click on your project settings and go to capabilities there you'll see the app sandbox. make sure it's turned on and then enable incoming connections and outgoing connections.