# I can't get the client script to connect to the localhost server, the TCP connection never happens

Tags: swift, macos, sockets, tcp

I wrote a simple client side program that creates a socket using

`CFSteamCreatePairWithSocketToHost function`

and connects to the server that runs on the local host on port 8080. It creates the socket just fine but it never connects to the server. I wrote the server in C. It didn't work and gave me a

`kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 72000`

and the only information that relays is that apparently the TCP connection couldn't be made don't know why though. So I tried to write the client side script in C too and added it to my Swift project bridging header and all but it still doesn't connect. It creates the socket just fine but it fails to connect to the server and I have no idea why.

But the same C client script worked when I compiled it using clang and ran it but didn't connect when I ran it with my swift project in Xcode. Is my mac blocking the libraries from making a TCP connection or something?

I don't even know what to search for. The only thing I found was an issue on a Github library called [starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/issues/561) which had the same errors I had and I'm not even using that library and the reply there was "the only thing we can discern from this error is that the TCP connection was unsuccessful".

Here's the code I used to connect to the server using Swift 4. The server is running on port 8080 on localhost.

```
class client:NSObject {
      var inputstream = InputStream!
      var outputstream = OutputStream!

      func setupNetworkCom() {
          var readstream = Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
          var writestream = Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

          CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, "localhost" as CFString, 8080, &readstream, &writestream)

          inputstream = readstream!.takeRetainedValue()
          outputstream = writestream!.takeReatainedValue()

          inputstream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
          outputstream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)

          inputstream.open()
          outputstream.open()
      }
}
```

I've also tried replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" which is the IP I specified for the server to run on but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click on your project settings and go to capabilities there you'll see the app sandbox. make sure it's turned on and then enable incoming connections and outgoing connections.